# strapi start command not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, strapi

I want to start **strapi cms** in the browser but Tells me :

> Make sure your **MongoDB database is running**

**In the event MongoDB is running**

How can I solve this problem?

[Mongod & mongo is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJy2r.jpg)

Comment: Well if it's actually running but the other program really does not think it's there then it's expecting to connect to something other than the `localhost` on the default port. You might want to check your configuration to see what it is expecting. You might then also realize this is **NOT** a programming question and you should be asking questions about **"configuring sottware"** on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Go to your project file. 
go to the `config/environments/development folder` and click on `database.json`. for `username and password` you leave it empty. and `host you put 127.0.0.1 port: 27017` as in the picture**

[image]

if you have finished the modifications you open two terminal:
on the first you start mongoDB by doing:

> mongod

and once mongoDB has started you start on the other console strapi by making:

> strapi start or npm start

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I had to update mongo to 3.6, stop the mongod service using

```
$ sudo service mongod stop
```

and run mongod in a terminal and leave it open.

```
$ mongod
```

The next time it seemed to recognise the mongo service started by the command

```
$ sudo service mongod start
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try removing the new plugins (if any) that you have installed.**

I have faced this issue 2 times

- Once I installed strapi command plugin
- Another time I installed seo plugin.

I do no the root cause. But removing those packages and re-installed worked.